# INSERT Failed: Error in MySql syntax in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a transaction procedure like this:

```
  INSERT INTO transaction(out, taxi_no, driver_name, odometer, date, mileage_out, hours_rent, remittance, total, shortage) VALUES (@out, @taxiNO, @drivername, @odometer, @date, @mout, @hours, @remittance, @total, @shortage)
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'out, taxi_no, driver_name, odometer, date, mileage_out, hours_rent, remittance, ' at line 1

I just copied the syntax and just change the values from my other project, it works well on my other project but when i tried to run the application, it gives me the error.

Comment: That error does not match the query shown. For example, the error shown displays a `odometer` field that is not present in the query

Comment: There is almost no way we can help you at present. The error doesn't match the query, as @Pikoh has just said. Where is the `out` part before the `taxi_no`? Where is `odometer`? I feel like this is either the wrong error message that you've given us, or it's not this query throwing it.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry i copied the wrong line of code.

Comment: So you have an column named `out` in your table? then try changing that line to this `INSERT INTO transaction(\`out\`, taxi_no, driver_name, odometer, date, mileage_out, hours_rent, remittance, total, shortage) VALUES (@out, @taxiNO, @drivername, @odometer, @date, @mout, @hours, @remittance, @total, @shortage)`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out` is a keyword in mysql so please add `backtick` ie `back quote`

Comment: oh i see, i didn't knew about it. Thank you so much it worked!